# Semaphore manipulation in finally clause

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I am reading Java Concurrency In Practice.

```java
public class BoundedHashSet<T> {
  private final Set<T> set;
  private final Semaphore sem;

  public BoundedHashSet(int bound) {
    this.set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<T>());
    sem = new Semaphore(bound);
  }

  public boolean add(T o) throws InterruptedException {
    sem.acquire();
    boolean wasAdded = false;
    try {
      wasAdded = set.add(o);
      return wasAdded;
    } finally {
      if (!wasAdded)
        sem.release();
    }
  }

  public boolean remove(Object o) {
    boolean wasRemoved = set.remove(o);
    if (wasRemoved)
      sem.release();
    return wasRemoved;
  }
}
```

I don't know why the `add` method has try-finally clause and the `remove` method does not.
I think it is ok to make it simpler like the following.

```java
public boolean add(T o) throws InterruptedException {
   sem.acquire();
   boolean wasAdded = set.add(o);
   if (!wasAdded)
       sem.release();
   return wasAdded;
}
```

What is the benefit of placing try-finally instead of simple statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL:DR:** The call to [`Collection#add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) could throw an exception after acquiring a permit.

---

The permits of the `Semaphore` in this case represent the capacity. When an element is added a permit is acquired *and then* there's an attempt to add the element to the internal `Set`. The result of calling `add` is then checked to make sure the element was actually added. If the element was not added then the permit that was previously acquired must be released. All good so far.

The issue is that [`Collection#add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) can throw an exception. The acquired permit must still be released in that case. The try-finally block guarantees that if the element was not added, either because duplicates are not allowed or because an exception was thrown, the previously acquired permit is released.

```java
public boolean add(T o) throws InterruptedException {
  sem.acquire(); // permit acquired before attempting to add element
  boolean wasAdded = false;
  try {
    wasAdded = set.add(o);
    return wasAdded;
  } finally {
    if (!wasAdded)
      sem.release(); // invoked if "set.add(o)" returns false **or** throws exception
  }
}
```

Since your version does not have a try-finally block the code is broken:

```java
public boolean add(T o) throws InterruptedException {
   sem.acquire(); // permit acquired before attempting to add element
   boolean wasAdded = set.add(o); // if exception is thrown permit is never released
   if (!wasAdded)
       sem.release(); // only invoked if "set.add(o)" returns false
   return wasAdded;
}
```

Removing an element does not have the same problem. No permit was released before attempting to remove the element, thus no permit has to be re-acquired if the element was not actually removed. This is still the case even if [`Collection#remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) throws an exception.

```java
public boolean remove(Object o) {
  boolean wasRemoved = set.remove(o);
  if (wasRemoved)
    sem.release(); // won't be invoked if "set.remove(o)" returns false or throws exception
  return wasRemoved;
}
```